# navigation bar is not hidden after pressing back button

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

When i perform segue `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToClientScreen", sender: nil)`
then i click back button in navigation bar then in my home screen navigation bar is not hidden

home screen Code ->

```
   @IBAction func nextBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToClientScreen", sender: nil)
    }
```

Client Screen Code ->

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated:  true)
 }
```

see in image ->

**open app then press next**
[image: All things is fine]

**and press Back Button here i want navigation bar**
[image: here is also looks good]

**and navigation bar is not hidden**
[image: here is an issue]

Comment: Can you show more code in `viewWillAppear` on Clients screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On First Screen Hide the navigation bar.

In the ViewWillAppear method, write the following code.

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

This will resolve this issue.